# What scope is required to call Executionhistory - List

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am creating a dashboard extension, and would like to call [Executionhistory - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/executionhistory/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Currently, the extension manifest specifies only the scope `vso.serviceendpoint_manage`.

I get my authorization token via

```
const token = await VSS.getAccessToken();
var authHeader = VSS_Auth_Service.authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);
```

I am able to successfully get a list of all service endpoints by using [Endpoints - Get Service Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get%20service%20endpoints?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

However, when I try to get the Execution History for a given Service Endpoint, I get a CORS policy error.

> Access to {devops rest api} from origin {marketplace url} has been blocked by CORS policy

I know CORS errors can occur if the PAT does not have the correct scopes [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/cross-origin-resource-sharing?view=azure-devops).

Note: When I try this locally with a PAT with all scopes, this call works.  So I am fairly certain I am missing an extension scope.

Which scope am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get service endpoint execution history, no need to set anything other, just set PAT token scope as **Read & manage** to **Tokens**:

[image]

You will see it is work to run this `Executionhistory - List` api.